# java.lang.StackOverflowError in android 4.0 and not in android 3.0

Tags: android, stack-overflow

```
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957): java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1711)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:749)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:972)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:416)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:295)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:269)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:942)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:405)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:400)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5038)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10978)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2092)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11083)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3398)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11083)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1524)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10981)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10981)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10981)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
01-31 12:52:53.020: E/AndroidRuntime(10957):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(Vi
```

Comment: Can you give some details about what you're doing?  You're not really asking anything right now, and stack traces aren't really going to tell us what you're trying to do.  Give us some context.

Comment: Am trying to build a grid view(with image and text) and the same code works fine in Android 3.0 tablet. But the while i run this in android4.0 tablet, the code crashes with the above stack trace.

Comment: If it's a big, complex layout there's probably not enough memory in the 4.0 tablet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stack is VERY similar to the stack you get when you have too many nested Layouts.  I would run layoutopt and see if you can reduce your layout hierarchy and see if it fixes it, as for Framework differences I can't say if they reduced this limit or if the newer controls increase their internal hierarchy layouts which pushed you over the limits.  Hard to say...

https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/layoutopt.html

Comment: Appreciate your help!! Finally fixed the number of levels in the layout and fixed it!!!

Comment: Wow! You are a lifesaver! This bug had me scratching my head for days. Complex layout was the problem. Once I simplified my layout and got rid of a few views - all worked well. Thanks!

Comment: At first I was somehow sceptic since I was removing views and still getting the same stack trace, but after removing some views and optimising other layouts, I managed to reduce, at runtime, the equivalent of 171 views being rendered, and the problem disappeared. Thank you for this answer. And `Android Device Monitor` with `Hierarchy Viewer` was indeed a great help.

Answer (score 2):

This error happend to when i was trying to use TextWatchers on two EditTexts.

The idea was if one EditText was changed the other should be set to "" and vice versa.

But the problem is i think that it presented a loop since setting the other to "" is also change and it would mean the first one should also be set to "" and so on and so on...